# Can a debian system be changed from non-rolling to rolling like Kali or is a clean install wise?

Tags: debian

Now Kali linux 2.0 is out and it has been transformed into a rolling release system.

On the official website there is a tutorial on how to upgrade Kali 1.x to Kali 2.0 by adding lines to sources.apt.

Question:
Is a system (debian) changeable from not-rolling to rolling release or is a clean install suggested, just because of that?

Answer (score 1):

What you look for is transforming Debian Stable to Debian Unstable (latter being rolling).
This *should* be possible and it *should not* break but it's nothing that one could encourage.
The Kali devs probably did one-time explicit work to make this transition not break but the Debian Devs cannot make sure this would work across every version at any time.

Also it's Debian Unstable. If you are fine with such this is no problem and many just get along with it well - but it'd still probably break more than a Debian Stable System.

Maybe you just backup, try - and if it works just go with it. Provided you are ok with Unstable (I'm running Arch with no problems for some time now too...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a clean install, just change the entries in [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) to use "testing" or "unstable" as distribution.

Then do 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get dist-upgrade'.